# Differentiation of Exponential Matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have been struggling with the following question while solving an optimization problem $$\min_{y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^G} F(y) = y^{T}\mathcal{K} + e^{-y^{T} \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{P},$$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is a positive vector in $G\times 1$, $\mathcal{A}$ is a positive matrix in $G \times J$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is a positive vector in $J \times 1$.

I tried to calculate $\nabla_{y} F(y)$ and $H_{y} F(y)$ using the chain rule, but as I'm not very comfortable with expoential matrices. I might need some help, since my formulas  $$\nabla_{y} F(y) = \mathcal{K} - \mathcal{A} e^{-y^{T} \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{P} \qquad\text{and}\qquad H_{y} F(y) = \mathcal{A} \mathcal{A}^{T} e^{-y^{T} \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{P}$$ don't agree with *Mathematica*'s.

Could anybody enlight me about how to derive this matrix?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're applying the exponential function to a vector argument, you must be doing it element-wise. The differential of a scalar function $f(s)$ is a scalar given by $$df = f' ds$$Similarly, when applied element-wise to a matrix argument $(X)$ the differential is a matrix given by
$$df = f'\circ dX$$where $\circ$ represents the Hadamard product.

Now let $X=A^Ty$, write the objective function in terms of the Frobenius (:) product, and take its differential
$$\eqalign{
  F &= K:y + P:\exp(-X) \cr\cr
 dF &= K:dy + P:d\exp(-X) \cr
    &= K:dy + P:\Big(-\exp(-X)\circ dX\Big) \cr
    &= K:dy - P:\Big(\exp(-X)\circ A^T\,dy\Big) \cr
    &= K:dy - \Big(P\circ \exp(-X)\Big):A^T\,dy \cr
    &= K:dy - A\Big(P\circ \exp(-X)\Big):dy \cr
    &= \Big(K - A\big(P\circ \exp(-A^Ty)\big)\Big):dy \cr
}$$
Since $dF=\big(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}:dy\big),\,$ the gradient must  be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= K - A\big(\exp(-A^Ty)\circ P\big) \cr
}$$
If you are uncomfortable with the Frobenius products, you can replace them with the trace function, e.g. $A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

To find the Hessian, you must know a trick for converting mixed Hadamard-dot products
$$M\,(a\circ b) = MA\,b$$where $A={\rm Diag}(a)$

So, let's find the differential of the gradient and apply that trick
$$\eqalign{
 dg &= - A\big(P\circ d\,\exp(-X)\big) \cr
    &= A\big(P\circ\exp(-X)\circ dX\big) \cr
    &= A\,\,{\rm Diag}\big(\exp(-X)\circ P\big)\,dX \cr
    &= A\,\,{\rm Diag}\big(\exp(-X)\circ P\big)\,A^T\,dy \cr
}$$
The Hessian can be identified as the matrix coefficient of $dy$ 
$$\eqalign{
 H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= A\,\,{\rm Diag}\Big(\exp(-A^Ty)\circ P\Big)\,A^T \cr
}$$

Comment: You can apply the same "trick" to eliminate the Hadamard product from the gradient expression.  Define the matrix $$E={\rm Diag}(\exp(-A^Ty))$$  then write the gradient as $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = K-AEP$$